# Discord js v13 Command Argument Options

Tags: discord.js

Atm I can't find it in the docs so before I continuous searching I think I better ask in here.

I want to use a dropdown menu roles but it has 2 command.
Command 1: /addmessage channel text  to create the dropdown menu text and add's it to a channel.
Command 2: /addrole messageId roleId to create that text made above into a dropdown menu role.
but 1 want to make it into 1 command.

So that the first argument will be a choices argument build with 2 choices to make. (addmessage / addrole)

Based on what choice they make, different next arguments will be used.

Like for example.
If addmessage = add then the next arguments to fill in are channel and text
if addrole = role then the next arguments will be text id and role id?

Or is this not possible and it's best to leave them as 2 commands?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html) and the [slash command builders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/builders), there is a [sub command](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#subcommands) option. In your case, the command might look something like this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

const command = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("add")
  .addSubcommand(sub =>
    sub
      .setName("message")
      .addChannelOption(opt => opt.setName("channel"))
      .addStringOption(opt => opt.setName("text"))
  )
  .addSubcommand(sub =>
    sub
      .setName("role")
      .addStringOption(opt => opt.setName("message id"))
      .addRoleOption(opt => opt.setName("role"))
  )

/*
  /add message <channel> <text>
  /add role <message id> <role>
*/
```

More Resources:

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder
- https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/builders.html